# Noise from the I2C - digital potentiometer

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a digital potentiometer controlled by Arduino, connected via the I2C bus (it controls volume). For some reason it beeps just by itself, even when no audio is playing. I have checked that it is def. I2C, as when I unplug the SDA&SCL then there is no noise (and I have many more connected to Arduino. Is there anything special about "de-noising" the I2C bus?

Comment: What do you mean by noise? what is the audio you mentioned? plrease add more details (at least the schematic), because I know that it is perfectly clear in your mind but if you can't communicate us the details we can't figure out what the problem can be

Comment: Best thing to do is take the I2C speed outside the audible range (if its not already there), try to put some distance between the I2C lines and speaker input lines and add an RC low-pass filter centred around 20kHz to the speaker's lines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea, but what you exactly mean by "take the I2C speed outside the audible range"?

Comment: Or where to put it? just in front of the speaker?

Comment: My suggestion may have been premature. Best you include your schematic and code so we can get a better idea of your problem.

Comment: Are you saying a digital potentiometer is making an audible sound?  Have you got pull up resistors in your circuit for the I2C bus?

Comment: I have replaced the I2C with SPI in the end, as nothing helped with removing this noise :(